# unresolved external symbol from curl, although it's listed in external dependencies

Tags: c, dll, plugins, build

I am getting the following error when building my project:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_global_init referenced in function twilio_send_message    test_plugin C:\Dev\ts3Plugin-ExtendedPoke\pluginsdk\src\twilio.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_strerror referenced in function twilio_send_message  test_plugin C:\Dev\ts3Plugin-ExtendedPoke\pluginsdk\src\twilio.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_init referenced in function twilio_send_message  test_plugin C:\Dev\ts3Plugin-ExtendedPoke\pluginsdk\src\twilio.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_setopt referenced in function twilio_send_message    test_plugin C:\Dev\ts3Plugin-ExtendedPoke\pluginsdk\src\twilio.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_perform referenced in function twilio_send_message   test_plugin C:\Dev\ts3Plugin-ExtendedPoke\pluginsdk\src\twilio.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function twilio_send_message   test_plugin C:\Dev\ts3Plugin-ExtendedPoke\pluginsdk\src\twilio.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_getinfo referenced in function twilio_send_message   test_plugin C:\Dev\ts3Plugin-ExtendedPoke\pluginsdk\src\twilio.obj  1
```

I have read many threads about similar problems, but I was not able to fix mine.
What makes me wondering about this error is, that all functions in the error messages are listed in their external dependencie header.
And when I jump into the function (for example "curl_global_init") it redicrects me into the right header listed under external dependencies. So there definitly is some linking.
Im not sure what the "__imp" before the function name in the error message means. How can i resolve this error?

Any help is appreciated :)

These are my includes in the twilio.c file

```
#include <string.h>
#include <C:\Program Files/Curl/curl.h>
#include "twilio.h"
```

Comment: What does the linking command line look like?  Do you list the Curl library after your object files?

Comment: Where did you list as external dependency? And what exactly did you list there? Including a header is different from linking the library implementing the functions declared in a header. Also, you should set proper include folder instead of including full absolute path into `include` directive.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler im not sure what exactly you mean with "linking command line". Im on windows and havent executed any specifc (mabye gcc?) commands. I've not listed any Curl libary. I just included the header. So that might be the problem?

Comment: @Gerhardhi did not list it as a external dependency directly. I just included the header and the header files are shown in the "External Dependencies" folder. So I thought that's fine. Okay, so I need to figure out how to link the curl libary. I've read some articles where the author explained how to build different curl versions. Do i really have to build them myself? Isn't there a more convenient way to link a libary?

Comment: What is a "external dependency folder"? Are you talking about some IDE you are using but which you did not mention? How do you compile your program? Which IDE do you use? Normally you don't need to build common libraries but can download precompiled versions. Where did you get the header? Should be same place where you get the rest.

Comment: @Gerhardh oh exactly. I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I've not compiled any commands. I'm new to c and their libarys, so I guess i'm missing something. I've read more about c libarys since your last comment and I might need vcpkg to install curl correctly?

Comment: Yes; your linker command line is probably the cause of your trouble.  Including the header tells the compiler how the functions should be called but does not tell it where the object code for those functions is kept.  Therefore, you also need to tell the linker (compiler) which library contains the object code for those functions, and you may also have to tell it where the library can be found.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Windows way. I don't think you need something like vcpkg.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay thank you very much! I'm going to read more about how to link libaries and then try to fix it :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have added the Curl include folder in Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.
Added the Curl lib folder in  Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories and added the Curl lib in  Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.
Sadly I still get the same error. Am I missing something elese?

Comment: Probably — but I don't know what.  I'm a dinosaur who doesn't use an IDE because I've never yet met an IDE that didn't confuse me more than it helped me, nor which allowed me to do things my way rather than its way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay. Im not sure what to do now haha

Comment: Try looking at other questions on SO (or even on Google) about linking with Curl on Windows.  There are probably answers there.  Specify your IDE, too.

Comment: I have found the solution to my problem. I have compiled the libcurl.lib in a command prompt with a x86 environment. But I needed it in a x64 environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-enable-a-64-bit-visual-cpp-toolset-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

If you use a static library, you need to define `CURL_STATICLIB`:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <C:\Program Files/Curl/curl.h>
```